# Patching a class to count number of created objects

Tags: perl, oop, testing, memory

I have a Perl library that uses many objects of some (about 3 or 4) classes during its operation.

In testing code, I'd like to ensure it isn't too many (I'm not talking about memory leaks, I know how to check that). To this end, I thought I could count every object used and check the maximum used during the run on the test data. Then, I would compare the obtained number to some guess about how many objects the library should use.

However, I've got problems implementing this. I thought about two possible ways:

- intercept `Package::new` and `Package::DESTROY`. However, this has a little catch that in that package, `new` doesn't always return a new object. Sometimes, it uses a preexisting one (the objects are used as immutables, so it shouldn't matter much). So I'd have to track each individual object to see if it existed before.
- intercept `Package::bless` and `Package::DESTROY`. This should work, but seems a little unorthodox.

The question is, which of those ways is more likely to succeed (maybe what is commonly used in similar situations), and secondly, how would I even implement the second way (would I have to override `Package::bless` for all packages in question or only base classes etc.).

Comment: Why are you concerned about how many objects are in use?

Comment: @Shwern: As stated in the question, to estimate the memory usage of the library. More precisely, I need it to ensure there aren't bugs causing eg. quadratic memory complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this (not tested):

```
my $Package_objects = {};
my $override_new = *Package::new{CODE};
*Package::new = sub {
    my $self = $override_new->(@_);
    # Interpolate $self as string to get "HASH(0x12345)"; save package name
    $Package_objects->{ "$self" } = 'Package';
    return $self;
};
my $override_dest = *Package::DESTROY{CODE};
*Package::DESTROY = sub {
    delete $Package_objects->{ "$_[0]" };
    $override_dest->(@_);
};
```

Probably this is most barbaric method, but must work without 3rd party modules ;)

Answer (score 2):

Store a hash of seen object ids to make sure you count each object only once.  You can do that using [Hash::Util::FieldHash](https://metacpan.org/module/Hash%3a%3aUtil%3a%3aFieldHash) or [Object::ID](https://metacpan.org/module/Object%3a%3aID).

An idhash has the advantage that it will not artificially keep the object alive.  As each object is destroyed its entry will be removed from the idhash.  It also has the nice advantage of working across threads.

```
package Foo;

use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

use Hash::Util::FieldHash qw(idhash register id);

idhash my %objects;

sub new {
    my $self = bless {}, shift;
    register $self, \%objects;
    $objects{$self} = 1;

    say "Creating ".id $self;

    my $num_objects = keys %objects;
    say "There are now $num_objects alive.";

    return $self;
}

sub DESTROY {
    my $self = shift;

    my $num_objects = keys(%objects) - 1;

    say "Destroying ".id $self;
    say "There are $num_objects left alive.";
}


{
    my $obj1 = Foo->new;            # 1 object
    my $obj2 = Foo->new;            # 2 objects
    {
        my $obj3 = Foo->new;        # 3 objects
    } # 2 objects
    my $obj4 = Foo->new;            # 3 objects
} # 0 objects
__END__
Creating 4303384168
There are now 1 alive.
Creating 4303542768
There are now 2 alive.
Creating 4303545192
There are now 3 alive.
Destroying 4303545192
There are 2 left alive.
Creating 4303638136
There are now 3 alive.
Destroying 4303542768
There are 2 left alive.
Destroying 4303384168
There are 1 left alive.
Destroying 4303638136
There are 0 left alive.
```

Alternatively, since every object created will be destroyed, only count when an object is destroyed.

Comment: Counting destroyed object would be no good, since I want to know the maximum number of objects *simultaneously alive*.

Comment: In that case, use an idhash.  As objects are destroyed they will automatically remove themselves from the hash.  I'll update with an example.

Answer (score 2):

With regard to how to intercept bless (not Package::bless, bless is a builtin, not some kind of method), most builtins are overridable (see http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Overriding-Built-in-Functions).  The replacement bless function would perform your tracking (if blessing an object into your target class) and then call CORE::bless to actually perform the bless.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the techniques used in

[Devel-Leak-Object-1.01](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/Devel-Leak-Object-1.01/)

I've used ADAMK's code as the basis for collecting various kinds of object creation/destroying statistics.